# Apache CXF Documentation Capability

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

[Enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/index.html) has a documentation mode and when you compile your code ***you get a documentation page for your web services*** (it is generated automatically and no need to write any other documentation annotations to add a documentation comment. I know Apache CXF has something like it. I need an automatic documentation generator, something like the Enunciate project).

***Does Apache CXF has same capability?***

**PS:** I use Spring at my application.

Answer (score 1):

December 2015 update: 
There are a few options to generate documentation , enunciate being the best OSS option by far. CXF doesn't have any plugins for this feature. 
However the best documentation feature , also has a Maven plugin is a commercial offering : http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/wsdldoc/.